# Angular custom directive function passed argument not binded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[image]

I am implementing a article/comment page. In the article page, there will be one article section, a list of comments, and a comment creation section.

I have a custom directive `myComment` which has `title` and `content` `<input>` and 1 submit `<button>`, just like youtube page.

In article_view's controller, I have an empty `commentInfo` object that will be assigned in `my_comment` directory. Then I invoke `onCreate` function which is bound to controller's `createComment` function.

the problem is that the commentInfo object is not emptied with `commentInfo = {}`,  after user type `this is title` and `this is content` then click `submit`, you can see the comment inserted to the list, but the comment creation area still has the value

Some relavent source code:

article_view.html

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in article.comments">
    <my-comment type="view" at="list" entity="comment" on-delete="deleteComment(comment)" on-update="updateComment(comment)"></my-comment>
</div>
<div>
    <my-comment type="create" at="list" entity-info="commentInfo" on-create="createComment(commentInfo)"></my-comment>
</div>
```

article_view.js (in controller function)

```
$scope.commentInfo = {}
$scope.createComment = function(commentInfo) {
    var newComment = new Comment({
        title: commentInfo.title,
        content: commentInfo.content,
        articleId: $scope.article._id
    })
    newComment.$save(function(data) {
        $scope.article.comments.push(data)
        commentInfo = {} //todo: input is not cleared after creation
        $scope.success = ['create comments success']
    }, function(err) {
        $scope.error = [err.data.message]
    })
}
```

my_comment.js:

```
app.directive('myComment', ['userService', function(userService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            at: '@',

            entity: '=',
            entityInfo: '=',
            onCreate: '&',
            onDelete: '&',
            onUpdate: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: '/public/article/my_comment.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.userService = userService

        }

    }
}])
```

my_comment.html

```
<!--create mode-->
<div ng-show="type === 'create'">

    <input type="text" ng-model="entityInfo.title"/>
    <textarea ng-model="entityInfo.content"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="onCreate(entityInfo)">Create Comment</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is the effect of two way data binding**.

In **$scope.createComment** function do this after **newComment** object is created.

```
      $scope.commentInfo ={}
```

Also there are some suggestion -

the following statement -

```
<button ng-click="onCreate(entityInfo)">Create Comment</button>
```

you don't need to pass **entityInfo** as it is pass to the directive through **two way data binding**.

So,**entityInfo** can be directly available to your  **$scope.createComment** function using **$scope.commentInfo**

```
var newComment = new Comment({
        title: commentInfo.title,
        content: commentInfo.content,
        articleId: $scope.article._id
    })
```

can be written as

```
 var newComment = new Comment({
        title: $scope.commentInfo.title,
        content: $scope.commentInfo.content,
        articleId: $scope.article._id
    })
```

EDIT CODE :

1. In $scope.commentInfo - commentInfo  object is bind to $scope.Also you mentioned two way data binding with **entityInfo** object in your **my-comment** directive.So,**$scope.commentInfo**  and **entityInfo** are pointing to same object referance.So, if one of them is updated ,it will update other.
2. In **commentInfo** object in **$scope.createComment** function, it is object crated locally and it is not bind to **$scope** .Again you are using isloated scope. It does not prototypically inherit. So, the directive cannot accidentally read or modify the parent scope. As **commentInfo** is not bind to **$scope**,it is not even exits in parent scope of directive i.e. controller.Also there is no two way data binding defined between **commentInfo** and **entityInfo**.So,these are **different object in different scope,one is at functional scope and one is at directive scope with each having their own copy**

Comment: in my directive, i passed the commentInfo from $scope.commentInfo. They are the same object reference, (refer to the demo video both inside my_comment and outside my_comment are updated as I type). Why one works but the other does not work.

Comment: @OMGPOP what do you mean by one works but the other does not work?I have checked your demo video. Textbox is not clearing after create comment.What problem you facing now?

Comment: $scope.commentInfo works, but commentInfo from argument does not work. aren't they pointing to the same object?

Comment: NO they are not same object.They are differant. $scope.commentInfo object bind to $scope object and  commentInfo  is local to the createComment function.You need  $scope.commentInfo  = {} and  commentInfo={ }  separate  for both object to reset it.

Comment: So when I write `<my-comment entity-info="commentInfo">`, the commentInfo inside the directive is a new object?

Comment: NO .It means  entityInfo inside directive  is bind to the commentInfo on $scope in parent scope.There is no new Object created inside directory of name commentInfo.

Comment: I still dont quite understand. If there is no new object creation, then both `$scope.commentInfo` and argument `commentInfo` must be pointing to the same object. Then why do you use `$scope.commentInfo` instead of just `commentInfo`